# Add suffix after specific after some characters and after number of characters Notepad++

Tags: variables, search, replace, character, notepad++

Id like to add `.pdf` text after
these characters: =pd
and after 6 characters behind characters above in Notepad++

**for example:**

```
for text:
=pd374069
=pd422552
add suffix:
=pd374069.pdf
=pd422552.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press ctrl+h or go into the find/replace window. Select Replace tab and choose the Regular Expression option.

In the find text box enter `(=pd\d{6}(?!\d))`

In the replace window enter `\1\.pdf`

It will transform

```
SPEC SHEET=pd374053;MANUAL=pd374069;SPEC SHEET=pd422552
```

into

```
SPEC SHEET=pd374053.pdf;MANUAL=pd374069.pdf;SPEC SHEET=pd422552.pdf
```